# Sonarqube RTC integration and capability

Tags: sonarqube, websphere, sonarlint, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I want to integrate RTC with sonarqube, requirement to do the same is to check the code with sonarqube and on successful result only it should get delivered to server.
As of now I have installed sonar server on my machine with JAZZ RTC plugin.
Now how to go about the above requirement, how to trigger the sonarqube test to every checkin, what all are the capabilities available to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround of this by using jenkins.
Installed Team concert plugin in jenkins.
Installed Sonarqube plugins in jenkins.
Configured RTC and sonarqube in global configurations of jenkins.
Created job in jenkins defining the RTC configuration, respository workspace to build, and sonar settings to perform sonar checks on the code checked out from stream.

Note:- Also installed and configured maven plugin in jenkins.